# Is product of Two Hermitian positive definite matrices a Hermitian positive definite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are both Hermitian and positive definite, and 
they are both $n\times n$ matrices, moreover, $AB=BA$. It is easy to prove 
that $AB$ is Hermite. Is $AB$ positive definite?

If your answer is that $AB$ is positive definite，then how to prove this conclusion?

If your answer is that $AB$ is not positive definite, please make an example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The matrices are diagonalisable, and commute so they are simultaneously
diagonalisable. So each eigenvalue of $AB$ is a product of an eigenvalue
of $A$ and an eigenvalue of $B$. Both $A$ and $B$ have all-positive eigenvalues...

Comment: Thank you, the answer is that $AB$ must be a Hermite positive definite matrix.